# Is most hydrogen in the universe in the form of plasma, atomic neutral hydrogen, ionized hydrogen, or molecular?

Tags: star, astrophysics, universe, hydrogen

I have had trouble finding an answer somewhere....

Some places say most hydrogen is plasma, such as the stuff stars are made of (mostly) and the 'warm-hot intergalactic plasma'.

Other places say neutral atomic hydrogen (H(I) to astronomers), such as the stuff in the interstellar medium, is the most common...

Comment: It would be better if you added at least one example for each of "Some places say..." and "Other places say..." Thanks!

Comment: Molecular hydrogen is known as H$_2$. "H III" would suggest hydrogen that has lost two electrons, except that since hydrogen only has one electron, there would be no such ion.

Answer (score 2):

@HurtHikes, I hope this answers your question,

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen), most Hydrogen is in the form of Atomic and Plasma states.

> Throughout the universe, hydrogen is mostly found in the atomic and plasma states, with properties quite distinct from those of molecular hydrogen.

Intuition says that because, as this [link](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/1999/ast07sep99_1) says, 99.9% matter in the universe is plasma, most Hydrogen in the universe should also be present in Plasma state.

> "99.9 percent of the Universe is made up of plasma," says Dr. Dennis Gallagher, a plasma physicist at NASA's Marshall Space Flight Center. "Very little material in space is made of rock like the Earth."

This [link](https://web.njit.edu/%7Egary/321/Lecture7.html) has the calculations to determine the amount of Hydrogen in Plasma in relation to the total amount of Plasma (if anyone is interested...)

> Stars are made of relatively simple stuff.  By mass, our Sun is 73% hydrogen, 26% helium, and only 1% of higher Z (atomic number) atoms.

> X = mHnH / r = density of hydrogen / total density

Though I am not sure about the actual answer about the same, I will be grateful if anyone can point out to the right answer. And although I have made every effort into the removal and rectification of errors, If there are any errors in my answer, I will be grateful if anyone can point them out.

Comment: Cam anyone please confirm if my answer is correct?